# Toggling Classes with a Switch/Case on an EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to toggle a class inside a div to make my sprite change directions on a key down event,
I seem to be having issues targeting the div to make the change, or i am incorrect in my switch/case.

```js
let sprite = document.querySelector('.charsprite');

sprite.addEventListener('keydown', moveChar);

function moveChar(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      if (sprite.classList !== 'faceup') toggle.classList.add('faceup');
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <div class="character">
      <div class="shadow pixelart"></div>
      <img
        id="mainchar"
        class="charsprite pixelart"
        src="/pspritesheet.png"
        alt="Sprite"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I did not understand why to capture keydown on image ?

Comment: I am very new to coding. This is one of my first projects. It's going to be a mess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (`sprite.classList !== 'faceup'`) is not correct.

You should use `!sprite.classList.contains("faceup")` because `sprite.classList` will return a array of classes.

Capturing keypress on an image is only possible if the user is focused on the image. So you should use `document.addEventListener(...` at the place of `sprite.addEventListener(...` but if you only want it when the user is focused on the image then you can go with this `sprite.addEventListener(...` one.

You can simply do something like this:

```js
const sprite = document.querySelector(".charsprite");
document.addEventListener("keydown", moveChar);

function moveChar(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      if (!sprite.classList.contains("faceup")) sprite.classList.add("faceup");
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.faceup {
  border: 10px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="character">
  <div class="shadow pixelart"></div>
  <img id="mainchar" class="charsprite pixelart" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x200" alt="Sprite" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the syntax for checking class in `classList`

```
let sprite = document.querySelector('.charsprite');

sprite.addEventListener('keydown', moveChar);

function moveChar(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      if (!sprite.classList.contains('faceup')) toggle.classList.add('faceup');
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture event from keyboard you need to have focused element. Since your image most likely not focused, and since it is seems to be a game, I suggest you to attach event listener to document, or to attach event listener to game area and focus it. To focus non focusable element, set it's tabindex, select element from DOM and call `.focus()` method.

References:

- [HTMLElement.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus)
- [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)